# Upload document to Salesforce using powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, salesforce

I'm trying to upload a text file in our Salesforce application using PowerShell.

The curl code which I'm trying to mimic in PowerShell is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: {SESSION_ID}" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F file=@document.txt \
-F "name__v=myDocument" \
-F "type__v=Undefined" \
-F "lifecycle__v=Unclassified" \
https://{server}/api/{version}/objects/documents
```

Here is the PowerShell code which I have written taking hint from the web:

```
$URL="https://{server}/api/{version}/auth"
$CT="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$User="user"
$Password="pass"
$SessionID=(Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body @{"Content-Type" = $CT; "username" = $User; "password" = $Password}).sessionId

$URL="https://{server}/api/{version}/objects/documents"
$boundary=[System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$LF="`r`n"
$File=Get-Content("....\test.txt")

$fileBin=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("....\test.txt")
$enc=[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
$fileEnc=$enc.GetString($fileBin)

$Body1=(
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name__v=`"kaz.txt`"; type__v=`"Undefined`"; lifecycle__v=`"Unclassified`"",
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
    $fileEnc,
    "--$boundary--$LF"
) -join $LF

$Body2 = (
    "file=$File; name__v=`"kaz.txt`"; type__v=`"Undefined`"; lifecycle__v=`"Unclassified`""
)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL -Headers @{"Authorization" = $SessionID; "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`""} -Body $Body1
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL -Headers @{"Authorization" = $SessionID; "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`""} -Body $Body2
```

None of these are working and I'm getting error

**PARAMETER_REQUIRED lifecycle__v: Missing required parameter : lifecycle__v.**

Comment: Why are you doing all that extra work with the encoding? Why are you passing all the parameters (`$Body1`) as a single string?  It's supposed to be a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: I tried that as well and got the same error again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the body and now its working fine

```
$Body = (
   "--$boundary", "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"test.docx`"", "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF", $fileEnc,
   "--$boundary", "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"lifecycle__v`"", "", "Unclassified",
   "--$boundary", "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"type__v`"", "", "Undefined",
   "--$boundary--"
)-join $LF

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL -Headers @{"Authorization" = $SessionID; "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"} -Body $Body
```